# UISearchController with updateSearchResultsForSearchController

Tags: searchbar, uisearchcontroller

I found how to implement a searchBar, but I don't know what to do in updateSearchResultsForSearchController method. All my data is fetched from CoreData. Here I put my code. If anyone had similar problem please tell me what to do.

```
@interface PlumbListTableViewController ()<NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *array;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *number;
@property (nonatomic) int sum;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PickerViewController *picker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISearchController *searchController;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *fileteredTableData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *products;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *recipies;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *searchResults;

@end

@implementation PlumbListTableViewController
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //All data from CoreData
    self.products = [Product allProducts];
    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.products count]];

    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
    CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"AddEntry"];
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    self.recipies = [coreDataStack.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self initializeSearchController];
     self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
    [self showTotalSum];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
  }


-(void)initializeSearchController {
    //instantiate a search results controller for presenting the search/filter results (will be presented on top of the parent table view)
    UITableViewController *searchResultsController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource = self;

    searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self;

    //instantiate a UISearchController - passing in the search results controller table
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];

    //this view controller can be covered by theUISearchController's view (i.e. search/filter table)
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;


    //define the frame for the UISearchController's search bar and tint
    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);

    self.searchController.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    //add the UISearchController's search bar to the header of this table
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;


    //this ViewController will be responsible for implementing UISearchResultsDialog protocol method(s) - so handling what happens when user types into the search bar
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;


    //this ViewController will be responsisble for implementing UISearchBarDelegate protocol methods(s)
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
}

-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {
 }

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"edit"]) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = sender;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        PlumbAddViewController *entryViewController = (PlumbAddViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
        entryViewController.entry = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    }
}


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return self.fetchedResultsController.sections.count;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ConfigureCellPlumb *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


    AddEntry *entry = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell configureCellforTable:entry];

    return cell;

}

-(NSFetchRequest *)entryListFetchRequest {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"AddEntry"];

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO]];

    return fetchRequest;
}

-(NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self entryListFetchRequest];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionName" cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs, updateSearchResultsForSearchController: is "called when the search bar's text or scope has changed or when the search bar becomes first responder."

So, within this method you want to update your table to show the proper search results. This is what mine looks like (yours will look different but the idea is the same):

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    //make sure model has only results that correspond to the search
    [self updateFilteredContentWithSearchText:[self.searchController.searchBar text]];
    //update the table now that the model has been updated
    [self.specialtySearchResultsTVC.tableView reloadData];
}

//helper method
- (void)updateFilteredContentWithSearchText:(NSString*)searchText
{
    [self.specialtySearchResultsTVC.filteredSpecialties removeAllObjects];
    for (Specialty *specialty in self.specialties)
    {
        NSRange nameRange = [specialty.name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (nameRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            [self.specialtySearchResultsTVC.filteredSpecialties addObject:specialty];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Brian thanks for your answer, I tried but something is not working. Can you please tell me what are you doing in for loop? what is `Specialty`, is a class? and what is inside this class??? `self.specialties` is an array with all data that you are showing in main tableView???? And should we use a `NSPredicate` in `updateFilteredContentWithSearchText ` . Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Yes, specialty is a class, and specialties is an array that holds all the possible specialties to show in the table. In my for loop, I'm comparing the text in the search bar to all the specialties in my array and adding the ones that match.